# PHP compare two dimension array

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I would like to know how to compare two two-dimension arrays value.

First array

```
Array 1
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => c
        )

}
```

Second one

```
Array 2
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => e
        )

}
```

I need to make my loop to compare the arrays and check the matched value. In my case, array1[0][0]=a matches array2[0][0]=a. If it matches, php will output some html.

My foreach loop

```
foreach ($array1 as $arrays){
    foreach($arrays as $array){
      //need to compare array2 here not sure how to do it.
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need to know if my loop could compare the arrays to check the matched value." – well, save your file and give it a try ;)

Comment: ....I don't have anything to try...:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($array1 as $k1 => $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $k2 => $val) {

        if($array2[$k1][$k2] == $val) {
            // $array1[$k1][$k2] is equal to $array2[$k1][$k2]
        }
    }
} // end of foreach
```

The `foreach($a as $k => $v)` syntax does the same thing as `foreach($a as $v)`, except that it also puts the key associated with the value into `$k`.

Comment: @mattbasta: No, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_diff_assoclike so

```
if(count(array_diff_assoc($array1,array2) != 0))
{
   //Arrays are not the same
}else{
  echo 'these following items are differing in throughout the arrays . ' . print_r(array_diff_assoc($array1,array2),true);
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Also take note of array_diff_assoc, it returns the array items that are found to be different to the  other array including its index keys.

Comment: It should be noted that this function is SLOOOOOWWWWWWW. Great if you've got small arrays, but it gets exponentially slower as you add lots of elements to them.

Comment: Amber got what I need. Thanks for the tip though. +1