# how to compare same values in array in php?

Tags: php

I am getting the values from database as an array

```
<?php
    foreach($this->getlist as $value){
        foreach($this->listOfdealers as $list){

?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value=<?php echo $list->nList?>
            <?php if($value->nSubList==$list->nList){echo 'checked';  } ?> />
        <label for="list_32"><?php echo $list->nList?>
        </label>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

I just want to compare two array values and display the checkbox checked when they are equal, but here there are displaying 16 checkbox instead of four,as I am using two for loops and I dont want that.

$this->getlist is an array that is returning from database

Comment: What do `getList` and `listOfdealers` represent?  Which one *should* relate to the generation of checkboxes?

Comment: Try to separate your Logic from Presentation as much as possible, makes code easier to read and manage :)

Comment: we need to know the logik behind ->getList and ->listOfdealears. The nest foreach does not seem right at first sight but i might be wrong.. just give a sample of these objects (print_r)

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937341/php-compare-two-dimension-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

from
[foreach-manual page](http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php)

so you can use the same index for getting the values

```
<?php
foreach($this->getlist as $index => $value)
{
$list = $this->listOfdealers[$index];
?><tr>
      <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="list[]" value=<?php
              echo $list->nList ?> 
<?php if($value->nSubList==$list->nList){echo 'checked';  } ?> />
      <label for="list_32"><?php echo $list->nList?>
      </label>
      </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in_array function in php to compare array values. You can check on http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php for further details. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below for your problem.
It is the sample code using the in_array and array_diff. You can use either of the functionality.

```
<?php
$var1 = array("test","test1","test2");
$var2 = array("test","test1","test2","test3");
$var3 = array();

foreach($var1 as $i)
{
    if(in_array($i,$var2))
    {
        //save the value
        array_push($var3,$i);
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
//var3 will contain the values that are common in two arrays

//Another Method using array_diff
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);

?>
```